# Create projects in Azure DevOps - permissions amendment?

Tags: azure-devops, project-management

In Azure DevOps we've got a number of Project Collection Administrators but they're seeing more projects than they need to - it's almost as though they should be standard users but with permissions to create projects.

Is there a way to set up a group so that people can only see the projects they need and have the ability to create new projects too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a project, you must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group or have the Create new projects permission set to Allow. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#prerequisites).

So there is no need to add users to the PCA permission group, just give them the "create new projects" permission.

[image]

Then on the Manage user page, you can manage which projects the user can access.

[image]